# What should I install to use namespace Windows::Devices in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, namespaces, device

Now I am going to connect to device using bluetooth, so I have got some source code.
It uses namespace Windows::Devices, but my visual studio gives me compile error.

```
using namespace Windows::Devices;
```

I guess I have to install some packages additionally, but I am not sure what I have to install.
If anyone knows, please help me.

Comment: This seems to be UWP example for C++/CLI and C#. Which one do you use.

Comment: I am going to use this in C++/MFC. I already installed c++ UWP tools.

Comment: You can't directly use UWP in C++.

Comment: C++/CLI and C++ are different languages (but MFC is just a framework). @S.M. Maybe he could use C++/WinRT (which is a standard C++17 library, not a Microsoft's extension to the language)?

Comment: I attached prefix namespace ABI like using namespace ABI::Windows::Devices, so it doesn't give me compile error.

Comment: But I want to know how can I compile without namespace ABI.

Comment: Sample project uses strange types like String^, Guid, and ref like in C#. Does anyone make a sense?

Comment: @DavidLee Yes, things like `String^` indicate it is Microsoft's C++/CLI language, not C++.

Comment: @s.m The Windows Runtime is a 100% native implementation. Of course you can use it from C++, e.g. through the C++/WinRT library, or the WRL.

Comment: See [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) to get started.

Comment: @hea C++/CX uses `^` as well, which is a much more likely candidate in context of the Windows Runtime. Unlike C++/CLI it compiles to native code as well.

Comment: Actually, it is C++/CX. I set /ZW on project settings. So it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) I'm going to assume that that's the programming language you are using. The most convenient way to consume Windows Runtime types from C++ is through [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt). It consists of both a base library as well as a code generator. The code generator is responsible for providing the *"projected types"* (see [Consume APIs with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-apis)), generated into namespaces such as `Windows::Devices`.

It's common for a project to generate the headers containing the projected types on the fly, that can then be included like any other header. A project created using the [C++/WinRT VSIX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264) extension does that. Those projects have a reference to the [Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/) NuGet package that contains the code generator, as well as project properties to drive it during a build.

Previously, the header files containing the projected C++/WinRT types had been delivered through the Windows SDK. They are still part of the SDK, and can be used by client code, even though it's preferable to use the NuGet package instead. You'll find the *Windows.Devices.h* header file under *%WindowsSdkDir%Include<WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>\cppwinrt\winrt*, so to use this namespace, that's the file you'll need to include.